# How to start and stop a multistep animation while calling start() and stop() in the console using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written following code for multistep animation.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
   $max: 100px;

.equilizer {
  height: $max;
  width: $max;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.bar {
  fill: DeepPink;
  width: 18px;
  animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-duration: 2.3s;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-duration: 2.1s;
}

@keyframes equalize {
  0% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  4% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  8% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  12% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  16% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  24% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  28% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  32% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  36% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  44% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  48% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  52% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  56% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  64% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  68% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  72% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  76% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  84% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  88% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  92% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  96% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Now by default the animation should be in stop mode. On the run of start() in console of web browser it should start the animation and stop() in console should again stop the animation. How will I proceed for this using simple JavaScript (I am recommended to not to use any external frameworks/libraries except simple HTML,CSS and JAVASCRIPT).

Comment: Since the animation is performed by keyframes tied to the bar class, how about you just remove this class and add another that just styles as a static pink bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `rect` elements `.style.animationPlayState` to `"paused"` or `"running"`

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    .equilizer {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .bar {
      fill: DeepPink;
      width: 18px;
      animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    .bar:nth-child(1) {
      animation-duration: 1.9s;
    }
    .bar:nth-child(2) {
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    .bar:nth-child(3) {
      animation-duration: 2.3s;
    }
    .bar:nth-child(4) {
      animation-duration: 2.4s;
    }
    .bar:nth-child(5) {
      animation-duration: 2.1s;
    }
    @keyframes equalize {
      0% {
        height: 60px;
      }
      4% {
        height: 50px;
      }
      8% {
        height: 40px;
      }
      12% {
        height: 30px;
      }
      16% {
        height: 20px;
      }
      20% {
        height: 30px;
      }
      24% {
        height: 40px;
      }
      28% {
        height: 10px;
      }
      32% {
        height: 40px;
      }
      36% {
        height: 60px;
      }
      40% {
        height: 20px;
      }
      44% {
        height: 40px;
      }
      48% {
        height: 70px;
      }
      52% {
        height: 30px;
      }
      56% {
        height: 10px;
      }
      60% {
        height: 30px;
      }
      64% {
        height: 50px;
      }
      68% {
        height: 60px;
      }
      72% {
        height: 70px;
      }
      76% {
        height: 80px;
      }
      80% {
        height: 70px;
      }
      84% {
        height: 60px;
      }
      88% {
        height: 50px;
      }
      92% {
        height: 60px;
      }
      96% {
        height: 70px;
      }
      100% {
        height: 80px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button>play/pause</button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <g>
      <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
      <rect class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
      <rect class="bar" transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
      <rect class="bar" transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
      <rect class="bar" transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
      <rect class="bar" transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
    for (let rect of bar) {
      rect.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var state = bar[0].style.animationPlayState;
      for (let rect of bar) {
        rect.style.animationPlayState = state === "paused" ? "running" : "paused"
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To play, pause animations using a `<button>` element

```
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
    for (let rect of bar) {
      rect.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var state = bar[0].style.animationPlayState;
      for (let rect of bar) {
        rect.style.animationPlayState = state === "paused" ? "running" : "paused"
      }
    });
  </script>
```

To play, pause animations at `console` you can use

```
var bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");


function start() {
  for (let rect of bar) {
    rect.style.animationPlayState = "running"
  }
}

function stop() {
  for (let rect of bar) {
    rect.style.animationPlayState = "paused"
  }    
}

// run animations 
start();

// pause animations
stop();
```

Comment: Surely you mean `for (var rect of bar) { ... }`? That variable declaration is the same as any other, and should be scoped - it's good habit. Also, weird mix of ES5/6.

Comment: I do not want to include any additional button on the webpage. while on the console if I run start() it should automatically start the animation. Same is applied for stop() to stop the animation. How will I do this?

Comment: @Sounak You are trying to start, stop animation only at `console`?

Comment: Yes. But it should display the animation on the webpage once I run   start() at console.

Comment: @guest271314 I have posted my requirement in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684019/how-to-start-and-remove-a-multistep-animation-while-calling-start-and-stop-in the console using javascript. Hope this post will be more understandable for you on what I want to implement.

Comment: @Sounak  Does `javascript` at Answer resolve present Question _"On the run of start() in console of web browser it should start the animation and stop() in console should again stop the animation."_ ?

Answer (score 0):

I can suppose, the best way is to write these functions where you add/remove class with the animation attached to it.