# How to start and remove a multistep animation while calling start() and stop() in the console using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nWf1.png)
I have written following code for multistep animation. But I want to get result as shown in above screenshot. i.e., only the black vertical bar would be shown once the webpage is launched.[stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAuzt.png). then as shown in the screenshot if I run a start() at console it should run the animation and if I run stop() at console it should be back to vertical bar.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
   $max: 100px;

.equilizer {
  height: $max;
  width: $max;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.bar {
  fill: DeepPink;
  width: 18px;
  animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-duration: 2.3s;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-duration: 2.1s;
}

@keyframes equalize {
  0% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  4% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  8% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  12% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  16% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  24% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  28% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  32% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  36% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  44% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  48% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  52% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  56% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  64% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  68% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  72% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  76% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  84% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  88% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  92% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  96% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Now by default the animation should be in stop mode. How will I proceed for this using simple JavaScript (I am recommended to not to use any external frameworks/libraries except simple HTML,CSS and JAVASCRIPT).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can turn the animation on and off by adding or removing the `bar` class from the elements in question:

```
var bars = document.querySelectorAll('rect');
for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++)
  bars[i].classList.toggle('bar');
```

Put that code in a function and you can call it from the console as desired, though for demo purposes (expand the snippet to see it work) I include it in a button's click handler:

```js
var bars = document.querySelectorAll('rect');

document.getElementById("startstop").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === "Start" ? "Stop" : "Start";
  for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++)
    bars[i].classList.toggle('bar');
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
   $max: 100px;

.equilizer {
  height: $max;
  width: $max;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.bar {
  fill: DeepPink;
  width: 18px;
  animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-duration: 2.3s;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-duration: 2.1s;
}

@keyframes equalize {
  0% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  4% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  8% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  12% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  16% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  24% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  28% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  32% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  36% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  44% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  48% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  52% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  56% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  64% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  68% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  72% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  76% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  84% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  88% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  92% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  96% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="startstop" type="button">Start</button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
    <rect transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you could change your CSS slightly to apply the animation only to `.bar` elements that are children of an element with a certain class, and then add or remove that class from the parent element:

```js
var barParent = document.querySelector('g');

document.getElementById("startstop").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === "Start" ? "Stop" : "Start";
  barParent.classList.toggle('barstarted');
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
   $max: 100px;

.equilizer {
  height: $max;
  width: $max;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.barstarted .bar {        /* ---- note this change */
  fill: DeepPink;
  width: 18px;
  animation: equalize 1.25s steps(25, end) 0s infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-duration: 2.3s;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-duration: 2.1s;
}

@keyframes equalize {
  0% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  4% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  8% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  12% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  16% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  20% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  24% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  28% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  32% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  36% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  40% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  44% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  48% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  52% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  56% {
    height: 10px;
  }
  60% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  64% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  68% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  72% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  76% {
    height: 80px;
  }
  80% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  84% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  88% {
    height: 50px;
  }
  92% {
    height: 60px;
  }
  96% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 80px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="startstop" type="button">Start</button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="equilizer" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <title>Audio Equilizer</title>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(0,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(25,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(50,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(75,0)" y="15"></rect>
    <rect class="bar" transform="translate(100,0)" y="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the post I do not want to add any additional button on the webpage. In the script start() and stop() functions should be there so that when I run start() in the console it should start the animation and if I run stop() again the single vertical line should be displayed.

Comment: And as I mentioned in my answer, "Put that code in a function and you can call it from the console as desired". As I also said, I just used a button for demo purposes.